# Exception when clicks Cancel button in JDialog

Tags: java, swing, button, nullpointerexception, jdialog

I am trying to implement a `JDialog` at the end of a program and collect the user's input. My problem is that when the user clicks the "Cancel" button, Eclipse shows:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException.

The program seems running OK though afterwards. I can still start a new game etc. What is the code that I need to add in order to get rid of this `NullPointerException`?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) Always copy/paste error or exception output.

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs you'll see that `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` returns `null` if the user canceled the input.

You should check your `String s` for not being before using it.

Comment: Thanks.Yes I did check the string s. But when the user clicks Cancel it still returns an nullPointerException. I'd like to know how to handle this and close the InputDialog (but still keeps the program running).

Comment: Then you should provide more code. From what I see I can't tell more.